# Count the number of different characters in a string and return an int array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm a beginner c# coder and I have wrote a small code which counts how many different characters are in a string and returns a List. I wanted to make this code much more efficient.

```
string s1 = "noob";
List<int> count = new();
foreach(var item in s1.Distinct()){
    count.Add(s1.Count(x => x == item));
}
```

The end result is exactly what I want, a List of int with values of 1,2,1.

However I'm fully aware that this is really inefficient (since I have to iterate through the string at each character).
I've tried using the LINQ GroupBy method but I was unable to assign it to either a list or to an int[] for some reason. (I don't know how to convert from IGrouping to array..)

My logic was in theory simple. Group all characters and for each group return how many of those characters are present and add that value to the array.

It pisses me off to no end that I'm unable to figure this one out on my own. I welcome any tips or guidance on this matter and thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GroupBy` instead of `Distinct` (we *group* equal charactes, *select* `Count` from each group and, finally, *materialize* as a list):

```
string s1 = "noob";

List<int> list = s1
  .GroupBy(c => c)
  .Select(group => group.Count())
  .ToList(); // ToArray(); if you want an array
```

Let's have a look:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", list));
```

**Outcome:**

```
1, 2, 1
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry! I've almost got all the pieces of the puzzle to this! Have to dig a bit deeper into this topic.

Answer (score 2):

> My logic was in theory simple. Group all characters and for each group return how many of those characters are present and add that value to the array.

Good logic

> It pisses me off to no end that I'm unable to figure this one out on my own.

Dmitry's given a good answer, but let's talk a bit about GroupBy, because it's confusing as ****

If you're used to SQL GROUP BY, this isn't much like that - it "stops half way"

In SQL a GROUP BY insists you have something you group on and for anything you dond't group, you have to supply some aggregation. Here's all the employee counts by department, and the max salary in the department:

```
SELECT department, COUNT(*), MAX(salary) FROM emp GROUP BY department

dept, name, salary
tech, jon, 100000
tech, jane, 120000
sales, tim, 90000

--results
tech, 2, 12000
sales, 1, 90000
```

LINQ doesn't do this when it groups; it runs the grouping but it gives you all the input data divided up into the groups and doesn't insist you do any aggregates

The same thing there but done by LINQ is:

```
employees.GroupBy(e => e.Department)

[
  { Key = "tech", self = [ { tech/jon/100000 }, { tech/jane/120000} ] },
  { Key = "tech", self = [ { sales/tim/90000 } ] }
]
```

That's some pseudo-json to describe what you get from a GroupBy. You get a list of groupings. A grouping is something "like a list", that has a Key property, and can be enumerated. If you ask for the `Key` you get what was grouped on (the string of the department name). If you enumerate the grouping, you get all the employees that have that Key

```
var groups = employees.GroupBy(e => e.Department);

foreach(var group in groups){
  Console.WriteLine("Now looking at the contents of the " + g.Key + " group");

  foreach(var employee in group)
    Console.WriteLine("  It's " employee.Name);
}
```

Prints:

Now looking at the contents of the Tech group
It's Jon
It's Jane
Now looking at the contents of the Sales group
It's Tim

Because this list of things is.. well.. an enumerable list, you can call other LINQ methods on it

```
foreach(var group in groups){
  Console.WriteLine("Now looking at the contents of the " + g.Key + " group");

  Console.WriteLine("  The count is " + group.Count());
  Console.WriteLine("  The max salary is " + group.Max(employee => employee .Salary));
  
}
```

Now looking at the contents of the Tech group
The count is 2
The max salary is 120000
Now looking at the contents of the Sales group
The count is 1
The max salary is 90000

By stopping half way and not forcing you to do aggregates, LINQ leaves itself open for really useful stuff

In short, GroupBy is simply a device that takes a single list:

```
Aaron
Albert
Bertie
Ben
Charlie
```

And turns it into a list of lists:

```
GroupBy(name => name[0]) //first char

A: [Aaron, Albert]
B: [Bertie, Ben]
C: [Charlie]
```

Just remember, that to avoid confusing yourself, name your variables well in your lambdas

```
list_of_names
  .GroupBy(name => name[0])
  .Select(list_of_names_with_same_key => list_of_names_with_same_key.Count())
```

Remind yourself that what you're selecting is a list within a list, You might want to not use a name like `list_of_names_with_same_key` for that; I use `g` for "grouping" and I remember that a grouping is some enumerable list with a Key property that defines some value common to all

It's not so useful in this example, but also note that GroupBy has [more overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0) that the basic one but the docs are really tough to read. It's quite common to use the overload that lets you choose a different value..

```
//produces something like a List<string department, List<Employee>> 
employees.GroupBy(emp => emp.Department) 

//produces something like a List<string department, List<int>> 
employees.GroupBy(emp => emp.Department, emp => emp.Salary)
```

The second one produces just salaries in the list of grouped items, which makes it easier to e.g.:

```
Console.WriteLine("  The max salary is " + g.Max()); //g is a list of ints of salaies, not full employees
```

---

And finally, it might help demystify SelectMany too - SelectMany is basically the opposite of GroupBy. If GroupBy turns a 1 dimensional list into a 2 dimensional thing,. SelectMany turns a 2D thing into a 1D thing. The thing you give to SelectMany should be a list within a list, and you get a single list back out (`outerlist.SelectMany(someInnerList)` results in all the inner lists concatted together).

You could literally:

```
employees.GroupBy(emp => emp.Department).SelectMany(g => g)
```

and end up back where you started

Comment: Wow! Now that's some nice info on this topic, I admit that GroupBy is (was) really confusing for me, but this made it clear. Thank you for the detailed answer and explanation! You have no idea how much this have helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
var counts = "noob".GroupBy(c => c, (_, cs) => cs.Count());
Console.WriteLine("{0}", string.Join(",", counts)); // prints '1,2,1'
```